# Spring 3.1 + Hibernate 4 - HibernateTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate

Spring's [hibernate4 package](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/package-summary.html) appears to have done away with HibernateTemplate and HibernateDaoSupport. I'm in the process of upgrading Hibernate from 3 to 4 in my Spring app and I have a fair few subclasses of Spring's HibernateDaoSupport and a couple of Hibernate callbacks through HibernateTemplate. Perhaps I'm not using the right search terms, but I can't find any info in the reference docs on how I should be refactoring these to ["use plain hibernate daos as explained in the reference guide"](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?124677-Is-there-a-class-to-replace-o-s-o-hibernate3-HibernateTemplate-with-Hibernate-4&p=406779#post406779). Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [javadoc of HibernateTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html) explains it. You should use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` to get a session, and use the native Hibernate Session API directly.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I know where to go from there. I've looked more closely at HibernateDaoSupport and if you strip away HibernateTemplate it just holds a reference to the sessionFactory bean; pretty sure my 'generic DAO factory' can implement that!