# HibernateDaoSupport.getSession deprecated : How to replace it to create Criteria?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, criteria

I have not much practiced Criteria and even less with the use of Spring classes such as HibernateDaoSupport.

I have inherited of a project where all Dao extend HibernateDaoSupport, and all methods are using Criteria by this way :

```
final Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(MyClass.class, "alias");
```

Since I migrated the project under Maven and upgraded the Spring version (3.0.4 -> 3.2.17), getSession is deprecated.

What is the best practice to refactore all Criteria creation ?

Thank you.

PS: made some research, not found a real solution for moment...so forgive me if it's a duplicated subject or if there is a trivial answer

Comment: is HibernateTemplate.execute suitable for your purposes?. It's get HibernateCallback as parameter with method doInHibernate(Session)

Comment: You should use SessionFactory instead of HibernateDaoSupport. As per :
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104765/why-is-hibernatedaosupport-not-recommended
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188633/hibernatedaosupport-in-hibernate-4-0

Comment: so replace this.getSession() by this.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() ? coz i dont want to refactore all the application (too much line code)

Comment: that's not an equivalent. Problem with transaction. getSession is deprecated since 3.2.7 so it's recent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, using the SessionFactory directly is good practice.

After research, this comes from the fact that in Spring 3, transaction management is now "optimal".
But, unfortunately, in this inherited project the Spring configuration (1.x) is horrible and it is not possible to use the SessionFactory without refactoring.

In the end, we opted for the HibernateTemplate instead of HibernateDaoSupport. Its getSession method for creating Criteria is not deprecated.