# Spring 3 and Hibernate 4 Dao

Tags: java, spring, dao, hibernate-4.x

I found HibernateTemplate is removed from Hibernate 4 and how should I configure Dao application context xml file?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818291/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-hibernatetemplate

Comment: well, I didn't find any details there and it seems not helpful enough. Thus I don't think this is duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in my DAO classes. And the `Spring` configuration is like this:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
      p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
      p:url="${jdbc.url}"
      p:username="${jdbc.username}"
      p:password="${jdbc.password}"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>my.package.entity.Account</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

So now you should use for e.g.:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void save(YourEntity entity) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(entity);
}
```

Change your `HibernateTemplate` to `SessionFactory`.

Comment: Thank you. Previously I have a DAO bean with a reference to HibernateTemplate, but now what should I do with it? besides, waht are the references needed for the spring config?

Comment: Edited the answer. Also this is all spring config you need.

Comment: Great! it works for save. but when i use it for showAllEntity(), it throws an exception.
public List<MyEntity> showAllEntity(){
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Enity").list();}

Comment: Try to use: `return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from " + MyEntity.class.getName()).list();`