# How can I findByExample(Object instance) easily without HibernateTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mybatis, dynamic-sql

I tried to integrate `Spring 3` with `Hibernate 4` and I found that Spring don't support **HibernateDaoSupport** and **HibernateTemplate** any more in Spring's `Hibernate4` package.I have to use native Hibernate Session API.

So,here is my problem:

> How can I findByExample(Object instance)(this is one method provided
>   by HibernateTemplate before) easily?

I have to splice sql by myself which is very painful.I have used mybatis before whose **dynamic sql** is very useful but I still don't think it is as easily as HibernateTemplate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10818291/spring-3-1-hibernate-4-hibernatetemplate

Comment: If your entity's pk is `int` instead of nullable `Integer`, you may find always the entity having pk `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate itself have this funcionality, using the Example criterion.
As you already have to use Hibernate's Session you could just do something like this:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(MyClass.class)
 .add( Example.create(object) )
 .list();
```

More info on [Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Example.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to take a look at Spring Data JPA Repository.

http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/10/getting-started-with-spring-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

Try with Spring data, another alternative could be write an generic dao class and injects the hibernate session on it.